# Cannot run commands in bash terminal - argument list too long

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, bashrc

Whenever I try to run "vim .bashrc" I get the error: "argument list too long"

Most of the threads about this seem to be focused on commands like rm or mv... but I can't even open a file to edit.

I tried resetting my PATH variable, but that didn't work. I also tried running it as /usr/bin/vim /home/user/.bashrc and that also didn't work.

Are there any other possible solutions?

when I run "set" it is extremely long, but I don't know which environment variable is the problem

Comment: Welcome, what happens if, to test, you rename the  `.vimrc` to any other dummy name?

Comment: `printenv` would likely be more useful than `set` here (iirc environment variables count towards `ARG_MAX`, but things like function definitions that are also shown by `set` don't)

Comment: ... my bad, you won't be able to run `printenv` either if `ARG_MAX` is being exceeded as a result of one or more long environment variables. However you should be able to run the shell builtin `declare -x` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
cp  ~/.bashrc  ~/.bashrc_backup    #  backup existing 

cp /etc/skel/.bashrc   ~/.bashrc   #  copy default into own

source  ~/.bashrc                  #  engage new one
```

then investigate what is wrong with   ~/.bashrc_backup

```
cat  ~/.bashrc_backup
```

as you can tell file ~/.bashrc is a critical component to a healthy setup so changes there can brick the box until that file gets refreshed from default ... this might be a good time to get acquainted with how to "boot into recovery" which can give you a root owned terminal session from which you can fix issues